The printFile and printFiles interfaces cannot execute properly
I am trying to use the printFile and printFiles interface from pycups on a Megachip Kirin V10 Virtual Machine.
I have the following files in a directory:
test@test:~/desktop$ pwd
/home/test/desktop
test@test:~/desktop$ ls
1.png 2.png test.png

When I run the following code：
import cups
conn = cups..Connection()
conn.printFile('printName','/home/test/desktop/test.png','test_job',{})
conn.printFiles('printName',['/home/test/desktop/test.png','/home/test/desktop/1.png'],'test_job',{})

I get this error:
cups.IPPError:(1280,'No such file or directory')

No matter which interface it is, 1280 exception messages will appear. The path is correct, pycups version is 2.0.4. What is causing this and how do I solve it?
When pycups version is 1.9.73, printfile will encounter a 1280 exception, but printfiles will execute normally. When updated to 2.0.4, both interfaces will encounter this issue.
